# Series Representation of Gamma Function

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, gamma-function, polygamma

The $\Gamma(x)$ is function That has derivatives in the polygamma form.
Can those derivatives be used to make a Taylor series? I've tried but I got stuck as soon as I find out That $\Psi^1(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and that 
$\Psi_0^2(1)=(-\gamma) ^2$

I am doing the series at $x_0=1$ and
$\zeta(z)$ is the Reimann Zeta Function and
$\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivatives of the gamma function are a pain.

Better ways to compute it
are Stirling's approximation
or the Lanczos approximation as described here:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation